# How filter specific hidden 'dot' file with rsync?

Tags: rsync, hidden-files

I'm trying to tell `rsync` to ignore my `~/.cache` directory, but it doesn't want to listen.

How do I filter a specific dot filename with rsync?

Here, for example, is an attempt to copy nothing but `~/.cache`. It also fails.

First, see the size of my `~/.cache` directory:

```
$ du -hs /home/yuzer/.cache
2.1G    /home/yuzer/.cache
```

Here's my attempt to copy it with ´rsync`:

```
$ sudo rsync -axvzuhhh --include='.cache' --exclude='*' "/home/yuzer" "/media/yuzer/device"
sending incremental file list
sent 18 bytes  received 12 bytes  60.00 bytes/sec total size is 0 
speedup is 0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command looks like it includes `.cache` correctly, but unfortunately it excludes everything inside it.

Try this:

```
--include='.cache/**' --exclude='*'
```